# Need suggested complete flow for the use case in terraform

Tags: terraform

Actually we bulit webapp from there we are passing variables to the terraform by

like below

terraform apply -input=false -auto-approve -var ami="%ami%" -var region="%region%" -var icount="%count%" -var type="%instance_type%"

I need to store differed clients state files in different paths how would I achieve this from my case as terraform backend does not support variables.

Answer (score 0):

The use case you're describing is something Terraform workspaces could solve. Relevant doc: https://www.terraform.io/docs/state/workspaces.html

The use case listed in Terraform doc is for separate environments (Production, Development, QA, etc) however this could also be used for different clients.

This doesn't change the fact that Terraform backends don't allow variables, but it would let you have separate states per workspace(client).

Comment: Hi thanks for the responce but to switch between workspaces is there any thing there in CI CD apart from manual command like select workspace need to switch the directory in Jenkins file